# Is there any equivalent of setbase() in C? How to set base to dec, hex or oct in c?

Tags: c

```
long int id;
printf("Enter Aircraft Id: (eg abeb11");
scanf("%x",&id);
```

The `id"` has to be read as hex value.
but I am getting the warning `format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]`

In C++, we can use `setbase()`. 
But I am stuck as to how to do it in C.

Comment: Do you know how to print output in C? How to read input? If not then start with that, and any tutorial or book (even pretty bad ones) should tell you exactly what you want to know.

Comment: The answer would be no. See your implementation's manuals or the C standard for `printf`, `scanf`.

Comment: Alas not. C doesn't really have the ability to implement ostream manipulators in the way that C++ does. You need to fiddle around with the `printf`-style formatters. But it *is* possible, just not as pretty as it is in C++.

Comment: You set the **d**ecimal base with `%d`, he**x**adecimal base with `%x` and **o**ctal base with `%o`.

Comment: It is appropriate to tag questions asking how to convert code from C++ to C with both language tags. Please don't remove the C++ one, it is fine in this case.

Comment: Am I in the minority thinking that the closure reason here is hogwash?

Comment: I think this is a perfectly sensible but misunderstood question.  OP is asking about _scanf_, already knows about `%x`, and wants to know how to scan a _long_ in hexadecimal, and none of the answers mention `%lx`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `%lx` format specifier to read in the long hex value.

Also `scanf` wants the address of the variable to read in.

`scanf("%x",id);` this will lead to **Undefined Behavior**.

Hence change as below.

```
printf("Enter Aircraft Id: (eg abeb11");
scanf("%lx",&id);
```

Comment: This answer is inapplicable since OP has edited to show they want input, not output.

Comment: The answer is wrong anyway, as the non-decimal converfsion type specifiers require a, `unsigned int`, not an `int` as you pass.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Updated the answer to meet the updated question.

Comment: I suspect OP does not yet know what "UB" means.

Comment: @kiranBiradar.. I forgot to put &id while writing the question. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @JyotiYadav please don't edit your question unless it's required because answers seems to be useless

Answer (score 1):

No there is not, the standard input/output streams in C are much more low-level and do not support the concept of a base (nor the concept of outputting "a number", they are character streams).

Just use [`printf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf):

```
const int number = 4711;
printf("%d in hex is %x; in octal it's %o\n", number, (unsigned int) number,
       (unsigned int) number);
```

will print:

```
4711 in hex is 1267, in octal it's 11147
```

And no, there's no standard way of printing in binary, you're going to have to implement that on your own if you need it.

To input, you need to match the type of the variable with the type implied by the formatting specifier:

```
if(scanf("%lx", &id) == 1)
{
  printf("the ID is %lu (0x%lx)\n", id, id);
}
```

the type of hexadecimal numbers is `unsigned` with the `printf()` and `scanf()` family of functions.

Comment: You may as well wack the octal one in too.

Comment: This answer is inapplicable since OP has edited to show they want input, not output.

Comment: Oh the joy of the moving spec.

Comment: @chqrlie Yes, of course, a silly typo. That's what I get for not test-running my code. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

C++ has a type safe conversion system for reading values from standard streams. `setbase(16)` is used to change the input base, not to specify the type of the target, which is handed automatically.

in C, the `scanf()` function uses a format string to specify both the type of the target variable and how to convert it, it has no information about the actual type of the remaining arguments. `scanf()` supports decimal, octal and hexadecimal conversions:

- `%d` converts an optionally signed value expressed in decimal into an `int` variable
- `%u` converts an optionally signed value expressed in decimal into an `unsigned int` variable
- `%o` converts an optionally signed value expressed in octal into an `unsigned int` variable
- `%x` converts a optionally signed value expressed in hexadecimal into an `unsigned int` variable,
- `%lx` does the same for an `unsigned long int` variable. There is no way to tell `scanf()` that the target variable is a `long int`, passing the address of a `long int` for `%lx` has undefined behavior, but it is accepted and works correctly for positive values on most current systems.
- `%i` converts a optionally signed value expressed in decimal, octal or hexadecimal into an `int` variable. The base is determined from the initial prefix (after optional spaces and an optional sign): `0` for octal, `0x` for hexadecimal, otherwise decimal.

Note that you should test the return value of `scanf()` to detect invalid or missing input.

Here is a modified version:

```
unsigned long int id;
printf("Enter Aircraft Id (eg abeb11): ");
if (scanf("%lx", &id) != 1) {
    printf("Invalid input\n");
    ...
}
```